# Can not execute a Full SQL backup

Tags: sql, batch-file, backup, database-backups

I am new in the SQL. Where I work I got a new type of job about automatize a Full SQL backup. Almost got it, it is working from the SQL Server Management Studio as a query. (by the way I have to do it on the Server) So I am trying to execute this query like this way "- sqlcmd -E -S EUTAX-WS\REMEK -i D:\Programs\FastGlacier\backupAllDB.sql" and its working my PC. But in the Server doesnt.

There is my batch file

```
sqlcmd -E -S EUTAX-WS\REMEK -i D:\Programs\FastGlacier\backupAllDB.sql
```

And there is my sql query

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) -- database name  
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256) -- path for backup files  
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256) -- filename for backup  
DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20) -- used for file name 

-- please change the set @path = 'change to your backup location'. for example,  
-- SET @path = 'C:\backup\' 
-- or SET @path = 'O:\sqlbackup\' if you using remote drives
-- note that remotedrive setup is extra step you have to perform in sql server in order to backup your dbs to remote drive 
-- you have to chnage you sql server accont to a network account and add that user to have full access to the network drive you are backing up to

SET @path = 'd:\Backup\Remek\'  

SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112) 

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT name 
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')  

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       SET @fileName = @path + @name + '_' + @fileDate + '.BAK'  
       BACKUP DATABASE @name TO DISK = @fileName  

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

And when I am trying to execute it, i got the following error:
*The server principal "" is not able to access the database "" under current security context.*

Somehow I should add permission, but I can not how to do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sqlcmd -U "username" -P "password" -i D:\Programs\FastGlacier\backupAllDB.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try giving permission to script containing folder i.e d:\backup**

In Windows Explorer, right-click the file or folder you want to work with.

From the pop-up menu, select Properties, and then in the Properties dialog box click the Security tab.

In the Name list box, select the user, contact, computer, or group whose permissions you want to view.

If the permissions are dimmed, it means the permissions are inherited from a parent object.

Comment: Or try to run the script as an administrator.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have full permission, on that directory. Still not working. Somehow I must add, full right when Im executing this query.

Comment: I hope the right user with full permission has been mapped to right database. Or else create new login with full permission. If that does not solve the problem, if MS SQL 2008 please install update SP1.

Comment: By the way, when Im executing the query in the SQL server 2012 its workin. But i have to run this from command line...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple batch script using the `SqlCmd` command line tool:

```
@ECHO OFF

REM Location to store the BAK files.
SET BackupDir=C:\Location\To\Save
REM SQL Connection information.
SET Switches=-E -S %ComputerName%

REM Pull online user databases.
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A IN (`SqlCmd %Switches% -W -h-1 -Q "SET NoCount ON; SELECT [Name] FROM sys.databases WHERE [State]=0 AND NOT [Name] IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')"`) DO (
    REM Backup each.
    ECHO Database: %%A
    SqlCmd %Switches% -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [%%A] TO DISK='%BackupDir%\%%A.bak'"
)
```